# client-server data exchange format

Tags: c#, c, client-server, erp

We create client-server erp system with huge amount(in the future) of data and use c# for client and c for server. We started with xml for small requests/responses and it looks ok for now. But  what is the best data exchange format for increasing amount of data per response(up to 100MB i think)?

P.S.

1. Highest priority is encode/decode speed.
2. We use Sockets to transfer data.

Comment: Best as in...? Smallest? Fastest to encode/decode? Most flexible? Most widely used? There are many options :)

Comment: encode/decode is most important for us

Comment: "Best" is very subjective, but you may want to check out [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) and [protobuf-c](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/) as something to beat.

Comment: Thanks. We will try to use protobuf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on what kind of data you are going to send to and receive back from the server. If “data” is some sort of a buffer with the known length and the usual operations are to put / get an object to / from the server, then I would recommend you to take a look at **HTTP**: it's a very simple protocol, there are many libraries and applications that support it, you can easily extend the protocol, add an encryption (**HTTPS**) and compression (gzip), and this protocol is easy to debug and work with.

If you want to send network packets that contain many data fields of different types, then you want to encode and decode such packet (serialize) before sending to the network. There are a plenty of open source libraries in the Internet which support both C and C# languages (you can even write your own implementation, it's not that hard). I would recommend you to take a look at **XML** / **JSON** (text-based standards for data exchange), you will find it much more easier to debug communication problem when working with a textural data.

Hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to take a look at JSON:
http://www.json.org/